# angularjs single page share the same DIV element

Tags: angularjs

I try to implement a single page app with angularjs

There is the route code:

```
angular.module('todomvc', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        'use strict';

        $routeProvider.when('/account', {
            controller: 'TodoCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'account.html'
        }).when('/', {
            controller: 'TodoCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'todomvc-index.html'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
```

The html of the single page is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" data-framework="angularjs">
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" ... >
    <script ...></script>   
    </head>
    <body ng-app="todomvc">
        <ng-view />

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="account.html">
              a html template segment(*) here  
              ///////////// this is the template of the first appearance. //////////////
        </script>    

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="todomvc-index.html">
              the same html template segment(*) here 
              ///////////// this is the template of the second appearance. //////////////
              But both appearance share a common template segment. How to remove the duplication?
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

By default, the second page is show up. After a user click a button on the second page, it will trigger `$location.path("account");` and route to jump to the first page. In my case, both templates share a div block, that is, a common part is load to both templates. Currently, the template segment is copy and paste to both areas as shown in above code. But the copy-paste is hard to maintain. How can I share the template segment between the two text/ng-template?

Thank you.

Comment: you can have the shared html in a seperate file and include that html using ng-include

Comment: no sure whether the ng-include will work within the <script type="text/ng-template" element.

Comment: just give it a try... let me know if it doesnt..., i guess it should work...

Comment: I really tried before, but it didn't work. So not sure, whether it doesn't work, or because my code is incorrect..

Comment: It should be <div ng-include src="'commonDiv.html'"></div> the ' is required, that is in ng-include src takes a javascript expression

Answer (score 1):

Define your common div in a seperate .html file and include it using the ngInclude directive.

```
<ng-include src="commonDiv.html"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend a module called [ui-route](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which provide a simple and easy way to maintain nested views and templates.